# $p(\mu | D, \alpha) \propto p(D | \mu) p(\mu | \alpha)$ bayesian inference

Tags: machine-learning, probability

$p(\mu | D, \alpha) \propto p(D | \mu) p(\mu | \alpha)$  bayesian inference. Why does this proportion hold? From bishop's PRML P77.
D is the data from a distribution.
$\mu$ is the parameters of this distribution.
$\alpha$ is the parameters of the prior distribution of $\mu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p(\mu,D \mid \alpha)=p(\mu \mid D, \alpha) \, p(D \mid \alpha) = p(D \mid \mu, \alpha) \,p(\mu \mid \alpha)$ would be a statement of conditional probability leading to a Bayesian result of $p(\mu \mid D, \alpha) = \frac{p(D \mid \mu, \alpha) \,p(\mu \mid \alpha)}{p(D \mid \alpha)}$

The next step is to say that the denominator $p(D \mid \alpha)$ does not depend on $\mu$ and  so $p(\mu \mid D, \alpha) \propto p(D \mid \mu, \alpha) \,p(\mu \mid \alpha)$

Finally, given the value of $\mu$, the model presumably has $p(D \mid \mu, \alpha)$ not varying with $\alpha$, so $p(D \mid \mu, \alpha) = p(D \mid \mu)$ and thus the desired $p(\mu \mid D, \alpha) \propto p(D \mid \mu) \,p(\mu \mid \alpha)$

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have $p(\mu|D,\alpha) \propto p(\mu,D|\alpha) = p(D|\mu,\alpha) p(\mu|\alpha)$, so your equation only holds if:

$$D \ \bot \ \alpha | \mu.$$